# How to apply CSS transition 2s then cancel although cursor is still hovering?

Tags: css, css-transitions

It seems I encountered something in CSS a couple years back, on *end* or *stop*, some term or syntax, for turning off an animation after a time, supplied in the declaration... but not having any luck on google finding that.  Is there a way to *snap back*/undo a transition while :hover state still active?

Comment: There's no efficient way that can dynimcally change the transition property when in action using pure CSS. However, I am relatively sure that jQuery and/or JavaScript accomplish a similar thing. For example, a JavaScript `function()` could be called during execution, triggering the stop of the animation, with the delay using `setTimeout`. This would definitely be something that wouldn't be to hard at all to accomplish.

Comment: After a bit of thought, would [`animation play state`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp) be possibly what your looking for?

Comment: @ Dumb Products Hmmm... usually if you have some zeros and some ones available, you can do anything you imagine; just is it worth the extra code.  In this case, I want it, really want it.  Maybe JavaScript then?

Comment: Also, by undo do you mean immediately go back to the regular state, or slowly going back with the set animation?

Comment: @DumbProducts - Please [don't ever link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com/). Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-play-state) instead.

Comment: @JosephSilber yes, I probably should have mentioned w3fools. But the particular page I linked to didn't have any faulty information inside. But you're right.

Comment: @ Dumb Products Had in mind a sudden change back to a :hover state with opacity still affected by hover, but the animation having played, gets cancelled.  From your mention of animation play state, I found the MDN page [full of awesome, keyframes[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUsing_CSS_animations) and...  I think I can get precisely what I need by learning about that.  Thanks for your interest in the question though. Appreciate the clue!

Comment: @JosephSilber AMEN brother.

Comment: @MountainMan can you check out the answer I posted a few minutes ago in the answer field?

Comment: @MountainMan ok. :) But can I have at least an upvote. Besides, by answer did have a whole paragraph about how to accomplish this with CSS. At least I tried. Thanks. :) (BTW Yes, I am a reputation monster :P)

Comment: @MountainMan next to my answer, you see the up and down button on the left? Click those. It increases the person's reputation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that `animation-play-state` would be what you're looking for. Note that no browser supports this property. Safari, Chrome, Opera and Firefox do support it with the prefix however, but note that the prefix `-moz-` (for FireFox), `-webkit-` (for Webkit-based browsers like Chrome and Safari), and `-o-` (for Opera) is mandatory for the code to function, or to be recognized at all.

For a more cross-browser solution, you'd probebly find yourself turning to JavaScript, or a library that utilizes it. For example, a JavaScript `function()` could be called during execution, triggering the stop of the animation, with the delay using `setTimeout`. This would definitely be something that wouldn't be to hard at all to accomplish.

You were mentioning in your question a `stop` script. jQuery (a JavaScript library) does have something of the sort: http://api.jquery.com/stop/. The only problem is that the transition has to be triggered using the `transition` jQuery code, but that shouldn't be so hard considering that jQuery is a short-hand coding language, and is really well documented.

Tell me if this helps.

And don't forget to accept this answer as correct if it helped. :)